# Amazon Athena ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION query giving missing column error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

```
ALTER TABLE "herdsysa"."temperature" ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (dt='2020-02-03')
```

I am trying to run this query on athena workbench but it says missing column at if (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 935dfae3-a4af-4438-be16-10d7884c9292)

anybody know how to make this work?

Comment: What happens when you execute without double quotes? `ALTER TABLE herdsysa.temperature ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (dt='2020-02-03')` . Same error? Also try specifying `LOCATION`

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy thanks a lot, the double quotes were the issue.

Comment: Glad, I could help. I have posted the same as an answer.  I would appreciate if you can mark that as an answer so that it will be useful for future users with same issue. @kamal11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `Double quotes` and execute.

```
 ALTER TABLE herdsysa.temperature ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (dt='2020-02-03')
```

Comment: I replaced the double quotes with a backtick.